# MySQL Database Specific Top (Amount)

Tags: php, mysql

I recently began learning PHP, and I set up a MySQL Server. However, I'm not very familiar with SQL, and I would like to know, how would I get the top amount of results (amount as defined by _GET["Amount"] that all have the same EventType as defined by _GET["EventType"]?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect(Info removed);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
$GetType=$_GET["Type"];
$sql= ""; //How would I do the action outlined above?
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Done";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've looked over this site and others, to no avail. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: 1 EventId int(7)  
2 PlayerName char(100) latin1_general_ci  
3 EventType char(30) latin1_general_ci  
4 Value char(110) latin1_general_ci 
5 Time char(100) latin1_general_ci

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: are you trying to **add** a record or retrieve a record?

Comment: Retrieve multiple records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry misunderstood your question...

Try this instead: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `EventType`='$GetType' ORDER BY `amount_column` DESC";

Run the query: `$sql_run = mysql_query($sql);`

The amount column in your table do have to be INT i think.

To echo out all the amounts you could then say something like:

```
while($sql_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_run)){
   echo $sql_row['amount_column'].'<br>';
}
```

- btw in your code you don't use the mysql_select_db() method, there might be a way around it, but as far as I know you do have to specify a database.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, I connect to the database in "mysqli_connect".

Comment: How would I make it only get the top ($Amount) rows?

Answer (score 0):

Before writing query you need to prepare the mysql table. If you have one, try to post here your table structure.

Comment: This is comment, not answer